# How do you say "made by"?

Tags: translation, grammar

I've stumbled upon a phrase which I cannot translate using dictionary itself. I would like to say something like

> "made by excessive use of technical terms"

, so far I've been able to come up with this but I am not certain about the "**made by**" part.

> Faris per ekscesa uzo de technika kondicxo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you posted the full sentence, and not just part of it, so that we can find a suitable translation. Generally though, *fare de* works for this. From [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#fare%20de):

> **fare de**. Prepoziciaĵo, enkondukanta la aganton post subst., esprimanta agon: *kelkaj postulas la administradon de la filioj fare de la asekuritoj mem*; *dum vizito al nia sidejo fare de fremdaj kolegoj*; *reguligo de salajroj k laborkondiĉoj fare de la ministro mem*. ☞ [far](http://vortaro.net/#far).

---

Note that it should be *teĥnika*, not *technika*, and that ‘terms’ in this context probably has the meaning of *terminoj* (as in, technical terminology) rather than *kondiĉo*. (But without the full context I can't be certain.)

Comment: Sorry for not providing the full sentence, it is “language not easily understandable or made by excessive use of technical terms”. This is a definition of an english word “gobbledegook”. Nevertheless “fare de” is the thing I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: That's okay, it seems that I got the right meaning after all! In that case it is certainly _teĥnikaj terminoj_ as well ;).

Comment: No, in *this* context _fare de_ doesn't fit. It should be something like "Lingvo ne estas facile komprenebla aŭ farata per la troa uzado de teĥnikaj terminoj". However, a literal translation with _fari_ doesn't sound good. I'd say "Lingvo ne estas facile komprenebla nek estiĝas per la troa uzado de teĥnikaj terminoj"

Comment: @CyrilRobertBrosch You are right, I misinterpreted the English sentence, for I read too quickly. Having actually now read the definition of _gobbledygook_ in my dictionary—which reads “language that is meaningless or is made unintelligible by excessive use of abstruse technical terms”—has made it clear to me that you are correct. However, the definition of _gobbledygook_ given by Peter seems flawed and oddly phrased.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that out, btw the definition comes from a dictionary I have on my kindle, which may not be the best.

Comment: @PeterUtekal You're welcome! I see; yea, I think the definition from the Oxford dictionary (the one above) is a lot clearer.

Comment: Ah, now I see we're dealing with a relative construction and a special sense of "language" here. So it should go "lingvaĵo, kiu ne estas facile komprenebla aŭ kiun karakterizas troa uzado de teĥnikaj terminoj"